# Casting number to other type using class

Tags: java, reflection, numbers

I have a method with a signature like this:

```
Number upcast(Number n, Class<? extends Number> type)
```

Note: I am sure my code will only ever pass the primitive wrapper types to this method (i.e. `Float.class`, `Integer.class`).

If the passed type is large enough to hold the passed `Number`, I would like to return this number as an instance of the passed class.

Otherwise, I would like to return the original `Number`.

How can I implement such a method, since I can't `cast` the argument due to type differences?

Currently, I have:

```
try {
    double max = c.getDeclaredField("MAX_VALUE").getDouble(null);
    double val = n.doubleValue();
    double abs = Math.abs(val);
    if(abs >= max) return n;
    //Part 2?
    //Can't do type.cast(n), or valueOf.invoke(null, n). 
} catch (NoSuchFieldException | IllegalAccessException e) {
    ...
}
```

How would I best implement this? The `valueOf` methods of the wrapper classes each only accept their respective types, so I can't, for example, pass a `double` to `???.valueOf`.

Would I need to check the type of the class using several `if`s and then call `n.???Value`?

Comment: As an aside, I can't imagine whether this method would be useful!  It returns an `Object`, and can silently return different types depending on the magnitude of the input.